# Pythonestic way: How to decide which modules to import with a flag in the constructor?

Tags: python, import, package, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to make a package and I'm figuring out a proper way to do it.
Basically its a cryptographic scheme that internally can operate with  64 bits arithmetic (numpy) or arbitrary precision arithmetic (mpmath).
So I made one module for the scheme (encryption, decryption, etc.) and one for all the "math" or special functions for each arithmetic (multiplication of polynomials, roots, etc.).

My approach was that in the constructor of the class scheme of the main file (scheme.py), the user can use a variable flag that if True it use one type of arithmetic and its False it use the other one.
So basically the constructor define which module imports.
I test this and it works, but when I make it like a package and import the package it stop working.
Errors like no module named arithmetic.

what I'm not seeing and how I fix it?
Which is the "Pythonestic" way to do something like this be free to tell me.
Now I'm simply making one arithmetic file, and that each function has these flag with an if....

Here is a dummy example that works:

example.py:

```
import scheme as sc

Arb_Arithmetic = sc.Scheme(False)
Arb_Arithmetic.sum()

Arithmetic_64= sc.Scheme(True)
Arithmetic_64.sum()
```

scheme.py:

```
class Scheme():
    def __init__(self, flag):
        if flag:
            import arithmetic64 as ar
        else:
            import arithmetic as ar
        self.ar = ar
    def sum(self):
        self.ar.test()
```

arithmetic.py:

```
def test():
    print("Arbitrary precision arithmetic")
```

arithmetic64.py:

```
def test():
    print("64 bits arithmetic")
```

My package structure is:

```
python_packace:
|---package_name:
|    |--- scheme.py
|    |--- arithmetic.py
|    |--- arithmetic64.py
|    |--- __init__.py (empty)
|--- setup.py
```

setup.py (also I try several things like using pyproject.toml)

```
from setuptools import setup

VERSION = '1.0.0'
DESCRIPTION = 'scheme '

# Setting up
setup(
    name="package", # the name of it
    version=VERSION,
    author="mmazz",
    author_email="<asd@gmail.com>",
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['numpy', 'mpmath'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)",
        "Operating System :: Unix",
    ]
)
```

Comment: Please try to think carefully about the intended logic. Where the code says `self.arithmetic = arithmetic`, the intent is to make the **local variable** `arithmetic` (which holds the `module` object for the module that was just imported **locally**) available later, as an attribute of `self` (i.e., the instance of the class that was created). Yes? Therefore, later, when you use that instance, and it wants to access `arithmetic`, will it be available as an attribute? Will it be available in the global namespace? Therefore, what should we write within `method_1` in order to access it?

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** either packaging (you [should have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) figured this out yourself before posting, for example by **trying** the code directly without bothering with the installation procedure, so as to create a proper [mre]) or the `import` system (the only interesting thing to understand here is that an `import` statement is an **assignment** to a name).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Karl. I think that I expressed myself badly (english isn't my first language). The way I did it it works, the problem was when i try to package it. I edit the post with a more clear and reproducible example. I don't know why this post it appears to be duplicate... the suggestion its not what I'm asking.